# Twitter batch follow email addresses

Tags: twitter

I have a list of 10,000 people I want to follow on Twitter but I only have their email address.

I DO NOT want to send an email to these people if they don't have a Twitter account.

Is this possible in less than 50 days and without arthritis?

Answer (score 4):

Just confirmed this works:

- Save emails to a text file
- Create a gmail account
- Visit contacts.google.com and import this text file
- Sign in to Twitter and import from Gmail account

Only existing Twitter users will be followed

Comment: True, I did so too many years ago. Didn't try recently!